# Why ParseQuery.FindAsync returns cached results in .NET API?

Tags: c#, .net, parse-platform

I'm use Parse.com .NET API.  I make query and then call FindAsync() method. First call returns data from Parse, but second and other calls returned old data, instead fetch it from Parse again(!). In .NET API not exists classes like ParseQuery.CachePolicy, so what can i do to get real fetching from server by any FindAsync call??

If it helps - my query:

```
            //Fetch user's scores from server (give me my old scores).
            var oldHighScoresQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery(HIGHSCORE_CLASS)
                .WhereEqualTo(USER_FIELD, currenUser)
                .WhereContainedIn(LANGUAGE_FIELD, requestLanguages)
                .WhereContainedIn(MODE_FIELD, requestModes);
            var oldHighScoreList = (await oldHighScoresQuery.FindAsync()).ToList();
//oldHighScoreList after second call contains cached data when server's data already updated.
```

Comment: It might be related to your particular implementation. Please share the relevant code to ve reviewed.

Comment: Alfabravo, implementation of what? I'm just use one API function. It works not as i expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually my posted bug was "assigned" here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/311128795748745/
so i hope that will be somehow resolved.
Until that i found a workaround - i make my every query guaranteed unique with special constrain like %base_query%.WhereNotEqual(SOME_FILED, UniqueValue), where UniquerValue guaranteed never equals to SOME_FIELD, so cache thinks that it is new (not cached) query and go to network.

That is my function:

```
        private ParseQuery<ParseObject> MakeUniqueQueryOf_HIGHSCORE_CLASS(ParseQuery<ParseObject> query, string fieldNameThanNotEqualsRandomValue) {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string randomValue = now.ToShortDateString() + now.ToLongTimeString();
            return query.WhereNotEqualTo(fieldNameThanNotEqualsRandomValue, randomValue);
        }
```

This is fits if time between your queries is guaranteed more than 1 second, if need more frequently queries - add milliseconds or ticks.
This is how i use it:

```
    //Fetch user's scores from server (give me my old scores).
    var oldHighScoresQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery(HIGHSCORE_CLASS)
        .WhereEqualTo(USER_FIELD, currenUser)
        .WhereContainedIn(LANGUAGE_FIELD, requestLanguages)
        .WhereContainedIn(MODE_FIELD, requestModes);
    oldHighScoresQuery = MakeUniqueQueryOf_HIGHSCORE_CLASS(oldHighScoresQuery, PLAYER_NAME_FIELD);
    var oldHighScoreList = (await oldHighScoresQuery.FindAsync()).ToList();
    //oldHighScoreList after second and others calls contains ACTUAL, NOT CACHED, JUST ACTUAL data.
```

Hope this helps to somebody in my situation.